# How to remove UTF-32 characters?

Tags: php, encoding, utf

I need to `INSERT` some text into `mysql` from `PHP`, which contains some `UTF-32` emojis. There are several methods for converting these emojis to `UTF-8` such as

```
$emoji = mb_convert_encoding($emoji, 'UTF-32', 'UTF-8');
```

Instead of converting, I simply need to remove all these emojis to have a clean text.

Comment: How are these UTF-32 emoji's stored in PHP?

Comment: @tkausl they are not stored in `PHP`, I read them from somewhere else and `INSERT` into the database.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to just

```
$result = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $string);
```

That code removes any characters in the hex ranges 0-31 and 128-255, leaving only the hex characters 32-127 in the resulting string

Comment: This will strip out _all_ UTF-8 characters, not just emojis.